# PHP override echo(ed) text instead of append

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a script as easy as this (in a foreach loop)

```
echo "hi i want to vanish in an instant";
echo "hi i want to replace the above text";
```

so i want to overwrite the text instead of appending.

In my mind there is no serverside solution for this without jquery/js, isn't it?

```
echo "<div id='placeholder'>hi i want to vanish in an instant</div>";
echo "$('#placeholder').html('hi i want to replace the above text')";
```

Why doesn't it work and how could it be done?

thanks again for your wisdom and help

EDIT: why the downvotes from stupid users, i want to visualise the progress the script makes. the script takes 3minutes to finish. Legit.

Comment: Why can't you simply *not* output the first string?

Comment: `$text = "hi i want to vanish in an instant"; $text = "hi i want to replace the above text"; echo $text;`

Comment: @deceze a. wolff because i want to visualize the progress the script makes

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
echo "<script>$('#placeholder').html('hi i want to replace the above text')</script>";
```

(You forgot the `<script>` tags)

Or you just replace the value of `$text` before echo-ing it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `script` tags.

You need to place your `js` code inside the script `block` and do make sure you adding jQuery library link.

```
echo "<script>$('#placeholder').html('hi i want to replace the above text')</script>";
```

---

You can make php variable and change it's value and when you need to output it just `echo` it out .

Answer (score 0):

js code should be in <script> tag

but why don't you use variable on server side to store what would you like to echo:

```
$out = "text 1";
$out = "text 2";
echo $out;
```

Answer (score -1):

I really don't get what you're trying. If you really want to overide for further use the first text you should put it into a display none span or div.

```
echo '<div style='display:none'>hi i want to vanish in an instant</div>'
echo '<span style='display:none'>hi i want to vanish in an instant</span>'
```

Or, if you really don't need the first text, as you are trying to overide it, just don't write it, use an if statement or something to match out what you want to write.